# Merge pandas df with how=inner and non-unique items

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that look like this:

df1

```
     a     b     c
0  foo  None   qux
1  foo   bar  None
2  foo  None  None
3  foo  None   qux
4  foo  None  None
```

df2

```
     a     b     c
0  foo  None   qux
1  foo  None   qux
2  foo   bar   qux
3  foo   bar  None
4  foo   bar  None
```

I thought that doing

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.columns.tolist(), how='inner')
```

would return

```
     a     b     c
0  foo  None   qux
1  foo  None   qux
2  foo   bar  None
```

and instead got this:

```
     a     b     c
0  foo  None   qux
1  foo  None   qux
2  foo  None   qux
3  foo  None   qux
4  foo   bar  None
5  foo   bar  None
```

Can I *merge* df1 and df2 to only find the intersection of those two? How? I don't understand how the inner join returns more items than are in either df individually.

Comment: @AntonvBR Sadly, that doesn't achieve OP's result. They want to retain only the same number of duplicates that were originally present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge does not know how to differentiate those identical rows, so they are duplicated more times than necessary.

I would suggest using a temporary column to record the `cumcount`, perform the `merge`-ing, and then removing the temp column after.

```
df1['d'] = df1.groupby(df1.columns.tolist()).cumcount()
df2['d'] = df2.groupby(df2.columns.tolist()).cumcount()

df1.merge(df2, how='inner').drop('d', 1)

     a     b     c
0  foo  None   qux
1  foo   bar  None
2  foo  None   qux
```

This works because `df1` and `df2` now have a 4th indicator column to differentiate duplicates:

```
print(df1)
     a     b     c  d
0  foo  None   qux  0
1  foo   bar  None  0
2  foo  None  None  0
3  foo  None   qux  1
4  foo  None  None  1

print(df2)
     a     b     c  d
0  foo  None   qux  0
1  foo  None   qux  1
2  foo   bar   qux  0
3  foo   bar  None  0
4  foo   bar  None  1
```

Comment: That looks reasonable. Any there any edge cases where this might not work as expected?

Comment: @Vishal If the dtypes of `df1` and `df2` are different. Otherwise I think this is pretty solid. If this is going into production code, make sure you write a few test cases for it.

Comment: How would I get the rows in `df1` and `df2` that are outside the intersection into `df1_` and `df2_`?

Comment: @Vishal Look into `how='left'`, 'right', and 'outer', and see where the nulls are being generated. By the way, thanks for the accept, and please consider upvoting as well.